# Random redis error on connection with magento CE 1.8

Tags: magento, caching, redis

I configured magento to run with redis backend cache, and I experience some connection errors in random situations.

Error stack trace looks like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:24:"read error on connection";i:1;s:1653:"#0 /var/www/mage/lib/Credis/Client.php(440): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
#1 /var/www/mage/lib/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(117): Credis_Client->select(0)
#2 /var/www/mage/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)
#3 /var/www/mage/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
#4 /var/www/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#5 /var/www/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#6 /var/www/mage/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#7 /var/www/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#8 /var/www/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#9 /var/www/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#10 /var/www/mage/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /var/www/mage/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

And it is caused both by core magento functions and my custom code.
Especially one of my helpers, where I use cache this way:

```
public function getSomething($id)
{
    if ($cacheResult) {
        $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
        $cacheKey = "something_".$id;
        $value = $cache->load($cacheKey);
        if ($value) {
            $value = unserialize($value);
        } else {
            $value = '';
        }
    } else {
        $value = '';
    }
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $result = $value;
    } else {
        $result = $this->api->getSomething($id);
        if ($cacheResult) {
            $cache->save(serialize($result), $cacheKey);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Any ideas why are these errors appearing?
Is it associated with my code? Should it be written differently?

It is running on VPS:

- vCPU 2000 MHz x 2 vCore
- 2GB RAM (4GB boost)
- HDD RAID 10

CPU usage is avg 25%-30% with no peaks and memory used ~600 MB. I don't have data related to disk IO utilization.

Comment: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis on several magentos and it works pefectly. I know that it does not really answer to your question but it will maybe permits to solve the problem. It permits to configure Redis for magento in local.xml and linked with https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession does perfect work for me.

Moreover, you can try to erase the keys directly in the server as sometimes the data are not really coherent.

Comment: but I use native magento module, no need to install additional extensions since CE 1.8

Comment: Tried to erase all contents in redis and did not help.
Error rate is very high, now for about 90 requests last hour, it was 10 error reports.